# Grunt Watch: Need to Save Twice After Every SASS Error

Tags: sass, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

When using `grunt-watch` while editing my SASS files, if I get a SASS error, I have to save twice after correcting the error for it to be resolved. Here's the sequence of events:

1. I include a mixin that doesn't exist in my SASS file and save
2. `grunt-watch` throws a SASS error
3. I fix the error and save
4. `grunt-watch` throws the same error
5. I save again
6. `grunt-watch` compiles correctly

Here's my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    // Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

        imagemin: {
            dynamic: {
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: 'assets/img',
                    src: ['assets/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                    dest: 'assets/img'
                }]
            }
        },
        sass: {
            dist: {
              options: {
                loadPath: require('node-neat').includePaths,
                style: 'compact',
                lineNumbers: true,
                cacheLocation: 'assets/sass/.sass-cache'
              },
              files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'assets/sass',
                src: ['*.scss'],
                dest: 'assets/css',
                ext: '.css'
              }]
            }
          },
        watch: {
            options: {
                livereload: true
            },
            css: {
                files: ['assets/sass/**/*.scss'],
                tasks: ['newer:sass'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            images: {
                files: ['assets/img/**/*.{png,jpg,gif}'],
                tasks: ['imagemin'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            js: {
                files: ['assets/js/**/*.js'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            html: {
                files: ['*.html'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            },
            php: {
                files:['**/*.php'],
                options: {
                    spawn: false
                }
            }
        }

    });

    // List plugins we're using
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch'); // Watch - http://goo.gl/yxNE0
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin'); // Image Minify - http://goo.gl/mkIRPE
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass'); // SASS - http://goo.gl/pCHySn
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer'); // Newer - https://goo.gl/3vBTnf

    // Plugins to run when we run the 'grunt' command
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'imagemin',
        'sass'
    ]);

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that mysterious `spawn` option in Watch actually needs to be set to `true` for this particular instance. Like most people, I really have no idea how `spawn` works, but it fixes the issue.

```
    watch: {
        css: {
            files: ['assets/sass/**/*.scss'],
            tasks: ['newer:sass'],
            options: {
                spawn: true
            }
        }
    }
```

You don't have to explicitly set the option to `true`, it's set by default so you can just not add it at all. I'm just including it here as an example.